# How do I create a not mandatory join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following 2 tables:

- ProductCombined - several product informations are stored here
- Productperformance - defines if a product is performing well

This is my current Query:

```
SELECT `prod_combined`.`sku`, `prod_combined`.`titel`, `prod_combined`.`preis_vk`, `prod_performance`.* 
FROM `prod_combined` 
INNER JOIN `prod_performance` ON prod_combined.sku = prod_performance.sku AND 
prod_performance.partner_id = 801 
WHERE (aktiv = 1) AND (active >= 0) 
AND prod_combined.sku = 1006224000 
LIMIT 5
```

In this version it is neccessary to have the field "active" be set with a value greater than 0.

But I need a query that will see the JOIN as not mandatory. E.g. if a join from prod_combined to prod_performance is not successful for this product it will be also fetched by the query.

Did I explain this adequately?

Regards,

Max

Comment: No, it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: try using LEFT JOIN instead of INNER

Comment: I want to modify the query. In this version it is neccessary that there is a existing row in prod_performance where the product exists an has partner_id = 801 and active >= 0

But this join should be optionally.

Comment: ive tried LEFT JOIN before. Doesnt work. I think that the WHERE active >= 0 is the problem in this case

Comment: do you mean that `aktiv` is coming from `prod_combined` table?

Comment: Let me explain it more:

in prod_combined is a field "aktiv" this must be in every way  = 1
in prod_performance is a field "active". This one is optionally.

Comment: then you should just ignore `AND (active >= 0)` altogether if it's not important.. AND use LEFT JOIN

Comment: active is important, when prod_performance can be joined. So now?

Comment: then put it in join clause. see my updated answer. if it can be less than 0, then use `>=0` to include 0 if it either 1 or 0 use `>0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work for you fine:

```
SELECT `prod_combined`.`sku`, `prod_combined`.`titel`, `prod_combined`.`preis_vk`, `prod_performance`.* 
FROM `prod_combined` 
LEFT JOIN `prod_performance` ON prod_combined.sku = prod_performance.sku
  AND prod_performance.partner_id = 801
  AND prod_performance.active >= 0
WHERE prod_combined.aktiv = 1 
  AND prod_combined.sku = 1006224000  
LIMIT 5
```

`LEFT JOIN` will ensure that if there is info to add from `prod_performance`, it will be displayed

Comment: The result row i got is:

`sku           1006224000 
titel        Klappentisch Porto
preis_vk      59.95 
sku        NULL
partner_id    NULL 
active        NULL
is_manual_set NULL`

I think the join doesnt join the correct line.

Comment: it will select NULL if no corresponding records found in `prod_performance` table - that's how LEFT JOIN makes it non necessary to have any results. what results did you expect?

Comment: Okay.. let me be more specific.

If a row in prod_performance can be found and prod_performamce.active is smaller than 0 the query should deliver no result.

Comment: then use `prod_performance.active >= 0` in actual JOIN clause - see updated answr

Comment: ive tried ur query. but when prod_performance.active is smaller than 0 it still returns a result. but the fields from prod_performance are NULL. Is there a way no result is returned?

Comment: you mean you don't want NULL returned either? so if there is no records - nothing gets returned? - this you should handle via your front end applicatoin really...

Comment: okay.. i hoped there was an easy way i didnt know. But no problem. I can handle it in my application, but i think it will cause a lot of script running time....

Comment: no it shouldn't. imagine mysql returning results as a table, then to create holes in that table would take more time than just return a table. in front end all you do is check `if( $value == NULL) { do nothing; }`

Comment: But now i return for each product one row. In the elderly query i only got rows for the active products ;)

Comment: then move active to `WHERE`: 
`WHERE prod_combined.aktiv = 1 AND prod_performance.active >= 0`

Comment: In this case i do not get a result, if there cant be found a matching record in prod_performance....

Comment: not if you using left join. honestly you u need to do a research on right join, left join and inner join... i can't help you further util u understand these...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    a.sku, 
    a.titel, 
    a.preis_vk, 
    b.* 
FROM 
    prod_combined a
LEFT JOIN 
    prod_performance b ON a.sku = b.sku 
    AND b.partner_id = 801 
    AND b.active >= 0
WHERE 
    a.aktiv = 1 AND a.sku = 1006224000
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Same problem here: partner_id and active are NULL in the result row. So i think that not the equivalent row in prod_performance got joined to it.